# What is a line in WEBVTT format?

Tags: html5-video, subtitle, webvtt, vtt

I see that WebVTT allows has something called "computed line" for each cue and it is either a percentage or a numeric number. Percentage is clear enough; I want to know what does it mean to have a numeric line. Is it the line-height as per CSS or is it something else?

Comment: possible answer - https://css-tricks.com/improving-video-accessibility-with-webvtt/#setting-1-line

Comment: yes, but this is a bit vague. What is "the height of the first line"? Is it based on `line-height`? Or something else?